# Toggling CommandField ShowEditButton conditionally occurs on next line

Tags: c#, gridview, rowdatabound, commandfield

I am trying to toggle whether or not a CommandField.ShowEditButton is true or false with the following code:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        clsEmployee employee = (clsEmployee)e.Row.DataItem;
        CommandField cmdField = (CommandField)((DataControlFieldCell)e.Row.Cells[0]).ContainingField;
        cmdField.ShowEditButton = _currentUser.FullName.Equals(employee.FullName);
    }
}
```

It works, but on the proceeding line; not the current one. If I am logged in as John Smith, this happens:

```
    +------+-------------------------------------+
    |      | John Smith                          |
    +------+-------------------------------------+
    | Edit | Jane Doe                            |
    +------+-------------------------------------+
```

I know I am on the right row, because this works (ShowEditButton is always true for the CommandField):

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        clsEmployee employee = (clsEmployee)e.Row.DataItem;
        e.Row.Cells[0].Enabled = _currentUser.FullName.Equals(employee.FullName);
    }
}
```

When I am logged in as John Smith, I get:

```
    +------+-------------------------------------+
    | Edit | John Smith                          |
    +------+-------------------------------------+
    | Edit | Jane Doe                            |
    +------+-------------------------------------+
```

with the John Smith Edit being enabled and the Jane Doe one being disabled.

How can I get the first method to work?

Comment: Which line works, and which one does not?

Comment: Where I set the ShowEditButton does not work, or at least not on the correct row.  Setting Enabled does work for the correct row.

Comment: What is _currentUser and how is this being set?

Comment: And what is your objective here, do you want to disable the Row when ShowEditButton is false?

Comment: The gridview shows all employees.  I only want the Edit button to show on the row that matches the logged in user.

Comment: Can you not just set the DataTemplate of the Row for DataGrid that has the edit button in it and do a binding if the current user is that one, then show the edit button?

Comment: If I cannot resolve this any other way, I will have to do it like this.  But I would prefer to find a way to ensure the Edit button is shown on the correct line without modifying the template.

Comment: I don't see in the code where you are setting the IsEnabled of the Cell based on this cmdField.ShowEditButton = _currentUser.FullName.Equals(employee.FullName);

Comment: I have added examples to the original post to hopefully make the situation clearer.

Comment: Have you debug it non what is the _currentUser and employee.FullName? Is the employee.FullName different on the second row, and how many times does this RowDataBound event gets called